# Transformation of Christoffel symbol

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I don't quite get the result that I should get.

We have $$\Gamma^\bar{\mu}_{\bar{\alpha}\bar{\beta}}=\frac{1}{2}g^{\bar{\mu}\bar{\nu}}\left(\partial_\bar{\alpha}g_{\bar{\beta}\bar{\nu}}+\partial_\bar{\beta}g_{\bar{\alpha}\bar{\nu}}-\partial_\bar{\nu}g_{\bar{\alpha}\bar{\beta}}\right).$$

Furthermore we find
$$\partial_\bar{\alpha}g_{\bar{\beta}\bar{\nu}}=g_{\epsilon\tau}\left( x^\epsilon_{, \bar{\beta} \bar{\alpha}} x^\tau_{,\bar{\nu}}+x^\epsilon_{, \bar{\beta}} x^\tau_{,\bar{\nu}\bar{\alpha}}\right)+x^\epsilon_{,\bar{\beta}}x^\tau_{,\bar{\nu}}x^\lambda_{,\bar{\beta}}\partial_\lambda g_{\epsilon\tau}.$$

Here, I've written $x^\tau_{\bar{\nu}}=\partial_{\bar{\nu} }x^\tau.$

Substituting the partial derivatives of the metric in the Christoffel symbol I get two terms. One is
$$\partial_\lambda g_{\epsilon\tau} \left(x^\epsilon_{, \bar{\beta}}x^\tau_{, \bar{\nu}} x^\lambda_{,\bar{\alpha}}+x^\epsilon_{, \bar{\alpha}}x^\tau_{, \bar{\nu}} x^\lambda_{,\bar{\beta}}-x^\epsilon_{, \bar{\alpha}}x^\tau_{, \bar{\beta}} x^\lambda_{,\bar{\nu}}\right). $$
By renaming the indices I obtain
$$x^\epsilon_{, \bar{\beta}}x^\tau_{, \bar{\nu}} x^\lambda_{,\bar{\alpha}}\left(\partial_\lambda g_{\epsilon\tau}+\partial_\epsilon g_{\lambda\tau}-\partial_\tau g_{\lambda\epsilon}\right) .$$

Now, for the second term I get $2g_{\epsilon\tau}x^\epsilon_{,\bar{\beta}\bar{\alpha}}x^\tau_{,\bar{\nu}}$ after using the interchangeability if the second derivatives, the symmetry of the metric tensor and switching dummy variables in one term.

So, at the end I have $$\Gamma^\bar{\mu}_{\bar{\alpha}\bar{\beta}}=g^{\bar{\mu}\bar{\nu}} g_{\epsilon\tau}x^\epsilon_{,\bar{\beta}\bar{\alpha}}x^\tau_{,\bar{\nu}}+\frac{1}{2}g^{\bar{\mu}\bar{\nu}}x^\epsilon_{, \bar{\beta}}x^\tau_{, \bar{\nu}} x^\lambda_{,\bar{\alpha}}\left(\partial_\lambda g_{\epsilon\tau}+\partial_\epsilon g_{\lambda\tau}-\partial_\tau g_{\lambda\epsilon}\right).$$

However, this deviates what I read in most forums and books. In the first and second term the co- and contravariant metrics should share one dummy variable. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Your very first formula (for the Christoffel symbol) already has a mistake, that leads to the indices disbalance. It has to be as $\Gamma^\bar{\mu}_{\bar{\alpha}\bar{\beta}}=\frac{1}{2}g^{\bar{\mu}\bar{\nu}}\left(\partial_\bar{\alpha}g_{\bar{\beta}\bar{\nu}}+\partial_\bar{\beta}g_{\bar{\alpha}\bar{\nu}}-\partial_\bar{\nu}g_{\bar{\alpha}\bar{\beta}}\right).$

Comment: Whoops, that was more of a typo as I was writing this on a cell phone. In my calculations on paper the brackets were set correctly.

Comment: All right, now you have a disbalance with indices $\epsilon$ and $\tau$ in the second equation. Can you please elaborate on how you obtain it?

Comment: Wrong brackets again. I'm sorry for my clumsiness. I think I have worked it out now, though. Take a look at my answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with $$\Gamma^\bar{\mu}_{\bar{\alpha}\bar{\beta}}=\frac{1}{2}g^{\bar{\mu}\bar{\nu}}\left(\partial_\bar{\alpha}g_{\bar{\beta}\bar{\nu}}+\partial_\bar{\beta}g_{\bar{\alpha}\bar{\nu}}-\partial_\bar{\nu}g_{\bar{\alpha}\bar{\beta}}\right),$$

we have $$\partial_\bar{\alpha}g_{\bar{\beta}\bar{\nu}}=g_{\epsilon\tau}\left( x^\epsilon_{, \bar{\beta} \bar{\alpha}} x^\tau_{,\bar{\nu}}+x^\epsilon_{, \bar{\beta}} x^\tau_{,\bar{\nu}\bar{\alpha}}\right)+x^\epsilon_{,\bar{\beta}}x^\tau_{,\bar{\nu}}x^\lambda_{,\bar{\alpha}}\partial_\lambda g_{\epsilon\tau},$$

$$\partial_\bar{\beta}g_{\bar{\alpha}\bar{\nu}}=g_{\epsilon\tau}\left( x^\epsilon_{, \bar{\alpha} \bar{\beta}} x^\tau_{,\bar{\nu}}+x^\epsilon_{, \bar{\alpha}} x^\tau_{,\bar{\nu}\bar{\beta}}\right)+x^\epsilon_{,\bar{\alpha}}x^\tau_{,\bar{\nu}}x^\lambda_{,\bar{\beta}}\partial_\lambda g_{\epsilon\tau},$$

$$\partial_\bar{\nu}g_{\bar{\alpha}\bar{\beta}}=g_{\epsilon\tau}\left( x^\epsilon_{, \bar{\alpha} \bar{\nu}} x^\tau_{,\bar{\beta}}+x^\epsilon_{, \bar{\alpha}} x^\tau_{,\bar{\beta}\bar{\nu}}\right)+x^\epsilon_{,\bar{\alpha}}x^\tau_{,\bar{\beta}}x^\lambda_{,\bar{\nu}}\partial_\lambda g_{\epsilon\tau}.$$

Substitution gives us $$\Gamma^\bar{\mu}_{\bar{\alpha}\bar{\beta}}
=\frac{1}{2}g^{\bar{\mu}\bar{\nu}}g_{\epsilon\tau}\left(x^\epsilon_{, \bar{\beta} \bar{\alpha}} x^\tau_{,\bar{\nu}}
+x^\epsilon_{, \bar{\beta}} x^\tau_{,\bar{\nu}\bar{\alpha}}
+x^\epsilon_{, \bar{\alpha} \bar{\beta}} x^\tau_{,\bar{\nu}}
+x^\epsilon_{, \bar{\alpha}} x^\tau_{,\bar{\nu}\bar{\beta}}
-x^\epsilon_{, \bar{\alpha} \bar{\nu}} x^\tau_{,\bar{\beta}}
-x^\epsilon_{, \bar{\alpha}} x^\tau_{,\bar{\beta}\bar{\nu}}\right)$$
$$+\frac{1}{2}g^{\bar{\mu}\bar{\nu}}\partial_\lambda g_{\epsilon\tau}\left(x^\epsilon_{,\bar{\beta}}x^\tau_{,\bar{\nu}}x^\lambda_{,\bar{\alpha}}
+x^\epsilon_{,\bar{\alpha}}x^\tau_{,\bar{\nu}}x^\lambda_{,\bar{\beta}}
-x^\epsilon_{,\bar{\alpha}}x^\tau_{,\bar{\beta}}x^\lambda_{,\bar{\nu}}\right).$$

Using the interchangeability of the second derivatives, the first term becomes:
$$\frac{1}{2}g^{\bar{\mu}\bar{\nu}}g_{\epsilon\tau}\left(2x^\epsilon_{, \bar{\beta} \bar{\alpha}} x^\tau_{,\bar{\nu}}+x^\epsilon_{, \bar{\beta}} x^\tau_{,\bar{\nu}\bar{\alpha}}-x^\epsilon_{, \bar{\alpha} \bar{\nu}} x^\tau_{,\bar{\beta}}\right)$$
$$=g^{\bar{\mu}\bar{\nu}}g_{\epsilon\tau}x^\epsilon_{, \bar{\beta} \bar{\alpha}} x^\tau_{,\bar{\nu}}+\frac{1}{2}g^{\bar{\mu}\bar{\nu}}g_{\epsilon\tau}x^\epsilon_{, \bar{\beta}} x^\tau_{,\bar{\nu}\bar{\alpha}}-\frac{1}{2}g^{\bar{\mu}\bar{\nu}}g_{\epsilon\tau}x^\epsilon_{, \bar{\alpha} \bar{\nu}} x^\tau_{,\bar{\beta}}.$$

Switching the indices $\epsilon,\tau$ in the last term cancels both last terms out because of the metric's symmetry. We are then left with: $$g^{\bar{\mu}\bar{\nu}}g_{\epsilon\tau}x^\epsilon_{, \bar{\beta} \bar{\alpha}} x^\tau_{,\bar{\nu}}
=g^{\mu\nu}x^\bar{\mu}_{,\mu}x^\bar{\nu}_{,\nu}g_{\epsilon\tau}x^\epsilon_{, \bar{\beta} \bar{\alpha}} x^\tau_{,\bar{\nu}}
=g^{\mu\nu}\delta^\tau_\nu x^\bar{\mu}_{,\mu}g_{\epsilon\tau}x^\epsilon_{, \bar{\beta} \bar{\alpha}}
=g^{\mu\tau}g_{\epsilon\tau}x^\bar{\mu}_{,\mu}x^\epsilon_{, \bar{\beta} \bar{\alpha}}
=\delta^{\mu}_{\epsilon}x^\bar{\mu}_{,\mu}x^\epsilon_{, \bar{\beta} \bar{\alpha}}
=x^\bar{\mu}_{,\mu}x^\mu_{, \bar{\beta} \bar{\alpha}}.$$

Now we have obtained the following: $$\Gamma^\bar{\mu}_{\bar{\alpha}\bar{\beta}}
=x^\bar{\mu}_{,\mu}x^\mu_{, \bar{\beta} \bar{\alpha}}
+\frac{1}{2}g^{\bar{\mu}\bar{\nu}}\partial_\lambda g_{\epsilon\tau}\left(x^\epsilon_{,\bar{\beta}}x^\tau_{,\bar{\nu}}x^\lambda_{,\bar{\alpha}}
+x^\epsilon_{,\bar{\alpha}}x^\tau_{,\bar{\nu}}x^\lambda_{,\bar{\beta}}
-x^\epsilon_{,\bar{\alpha}}x^\tau_{,\bar{\beta}}x^\lambda_{,\bar{\nu}}\right).$$

Switching the indices $\epsilon\leftrightarrow \lambda$ in the second term of the remaining bracket and $\epsilon\rightarrow\lambda\rightarrow\tau\rightarrow\epsilon$ in the third term, we find: $$\frac{1}{2}g^{\bar{\mu}\bar{\nu}}\partial_\lambda g_{\epsilon\tau}\left(x^\epsilon_{,\bar{\beta}}x^\tau_{,\bar{\nu}}x^\lambda_{,\bar{\alpha}}
+x^\epsilon_{,\bar{\alpha}}x^\tau_{,\bar{\nu}}x^\lambda_{,\bar{\beta}}
-x^\epsilon_{,\bar{\alpha}}x^\tau_{,\bar{\beta}}x^\lambda_{,\bar{\nu}}\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}g^{\bar{\mu}\bar{\nu}}x^\epsilon_{,\bar{\beta}}x^\tau_{,\bar{\nu}}x^\lambda_{,\bar{\alpha}}
\left(\partial_\lambda g_{\epsilon\tau}
+\partial_\epsilon g_{\lambda\tau}
-\partial_\tau g_{\epsilon\lambda}\right).$$

As before, we now introduce the barless indices: $$g^{\mu\nu}x^\bar{\mu}_{,\mu}x^\bar{\nu}_{,\nu}x^\epsilon_{,\bar{\beta}}x^\tau_{,\bar{\nu}}x^\lambda_{,\bar{\alpha}}
=\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}\delta^\tau_\nu x^\bar{\mu}_{,\mu} x^\epsilon_{,\bar{\beta}}x^\lambda_{,\bar{\alpha}}
=x^\bar{\mu}_{,\mu} x^\epsilon_{,\bar{\beta}}x^\lambda_{,\bar{\alpha}}
\cdot\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\tau}.$$

At last, we are left with: $$x^\bar{\mu}_{,\mu} x^\epsilon_{,\bar{\beta}}x^\lambda_{,\bar{\alpha}}
\cdot\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\tau}\left(\partial_\lambda g_{\epsilon\tau}
+\partial_\epsilon g_{\lambda\tau}
-\partial_\tau g_{\epsilon\lambda}\right)
=x^\bar{\mu}_{,\mu} x^\epsilon_{,\bar{\beta}}x^\lambda_{,\bar{\alpha}}
\cdot\Gamma^\mu_{\lambda\epsilon}.$$

Now we have obtained the following: $$\Gamma^\bar{\mu}_{\bar{\alpha}\bar{\beta}}
=x^\bar{\mu}_{,\mu}x^\mu_{, \bar{\alpha}\bar{\beta}}
+x^\bar{\mu}_{,\mu}x^\lambda_{,\bar{\alpha}}x^\epsilon_{,\bar{\beta}}
\cdot\Gamma^\mu_{\lambda\epsilon}.$$

This is the sought result.